# How to build an infinite scroll list in both directions (left and right) with React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm building a month view calendar and need to be able to swipe left and right for next and previous months.

I'm currently using a horizontal FlatList for this, which works great going forward in time (scrolling right).  It just adds months to the end of the list.  But I can't figure out how to effectively scroll back in time (scrolling left).  When I add items to the left side of the data, the scroll position gets jerky.

I am resetting the scroll index when a new item is added to the beginning of the data array, and that works in a perfect world.  But the problem comes when a scroll action is in motion while the index is being updated.  In that case, the scroll position gets jerky.

Has anyone solved this problem?

Comment: have you found a solution? I faced the same problem and looking for the solution